# Composition (Product) Of Permutations?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, function-and-relation-composition

I'm currently doing work on discrete mathematics in my free time and am having some difficulties with understanding some questions pertaining to Relations and Functions. To be specific, I'm stuck on the following practice question:

> Let $P_1 = (3~4~1~2~5)$ and $P_2 = (3~5~1~2~4)$ be two permutations.
>
> Find the following permutation
>           $$P_1^{-1} \circ P_2$$

So $P_1^{-1}$ could be $(4~2~3~1~5)$ and we leave $P_2$ at $(3~5~1~2~4)$.

Would it work to do it in this manner:

$$P_1^{-1}(P_2(1)) = P_1^{-1}(3) = 3$$

I don't really understand how to do composition, how would I find the resulting group? Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: (-1). did you even read my answer at least one time  to your last night question?

Comment: Yea but I don't understand how you end up with two smaller groups rather than just ONE group of length five. Sorry :/

Comment: @RaziehNoori is the inverse of the permutation for P1 that I wrote out at least correct?

Comment: $p_2=(3,  5,  1, 2, 4)$ means it $p_2(1)=2$ not $3$

Comment: WOW I've completely misunderstood until now. That is to say that in p2 two points to four correct? If thats the case then I totally get it and thanks.

Comment: happy hear it :)

Comment: @RaziehNoori That's not necessarily true. Sometimes permutations are written as lists. If the permutations are written as lists, then $p_2(1)$ is indeed $3$. I kind of suspect the OP's permutations are written with list notation, not cycle notation.

Comment: @pjs36 oh, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect you're learning permutations using the so-called "list notation". If this is the case, then writing $P_1 = (3~4~1~2~5)$ is simply specifying the outputs, like you'd initially thought;

$$(3~4~1~2~5) = \big(P_1(1)~P_1(2)~P_1(3)~P_1(4)~P_1(5)\big).$$

For inverses, I think a picture helps.

[image]

So, if we have $P_1(1) = 3$, then we must have $1 = P_1^{-1}(3)$ (if you like, by applying $P_1^{-1}$ to both sides).

In this way, we must have

$$P_1^{-1} = (3~4~1~2~5)$$

by essentially writing down the position each number occurred in $P_1$ (i.e., in $P_1$, we wrote $1$ in the third spot. So in $P_1^{-1}$, we'll write $3$ in the first spot.

---

Now that that's out of the way, I like your plan for computing the composition. But with the correct $P_1^{-1}$, let's see what happens:

\begin{align*}
P_1^{-1}(P_2(1)) &= P_1^{-1}(3) = 1 \\
\\
P_1^{-1}(P_2(2)) &= P_1^{-1}(5) = 5, \text{ etc.} 
\end{align*}

Alternatively, we could draw!

[image]

Comment: Or, evidently, "[one line notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Definition_and_one-line_notation)" it's called by Wikipedia. Compare with the [cycle notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation) used elsewhere.

Comment: Oh my god what an answer, thank you SO MUCH! Yea, this is 100% the way I'm learning list notation.

Comment: Usually the solution to the confusion is to use square brackets. I guess not everybody's in the know on that one.